# Execute Javascript function with an Seam EL expression

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

I have an issue with executing an javascript code, that contains an EL expression.
The javascript is called when a file upload is completed.

```
<rich:fileUpload
 ajaxSingle="true" autoclear="true" 
 fileUploadListener="#{bean.uploadListener}" 
 onuploadcomplete="alert('#{bean.updatedValue}');">
```

The problem is that the value of **updatedValue** is updated inside **uploadListener** method, and i need the new value of it.

P.S. I do really need to execute a javascript function on complete

Comment: @SillentTroll Glad to hear you solved the problem.  When you get the chance please add what you placed in your update as an answer to your question and accept that answer so that others who find this question will benefit.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.
Added `<a4j:support event="oncomplete" data="{bean.updatedValue}"  oncomplete="alert(data)"/>`

**Read the manuals ;)**